# Does a PCI device like PCI card reader or PCI usb host controller need to have a device attached to it to perform DMA attack

Tags: devices, pci

Am beginner to Unix systems and i have a simple idea about DMA attacks.

While trying to install Qubes OS i want to know if it's safe to install it directly from the hard disk, assuming the PCI devices' firmware is infected and/or vulnerable to DMA attack.

Is it possible for DMA attack to be triggered if there is no devices attached to it.

What i mean is for example : if a DMA attack through PCI usb host controller, require usb plugged in to be used to access memory ?

Comment: I'm confused. DMA attacks happen through your hardware. Your OS has no saying in them. If you have a device with a malicious firmware that has DMA access, it has DMA access. So – what's the question?

Comment: @Marcus What i mean is for example : if a DMA attack through PCI usb host controller, require usb plugged in to be used to access memory ?

Comment: no, the controller is what does the DMA access.

Comment: @Marcus That means the only mitigation to at least minimize the risk is to unplug the removable PCI devices, isn't there a counter-attack for this attack ?

Comment: Don't forget [IOMMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input%E2%80%93output_memory_management_unit) with various names on on various hardware: Intel's vt-d , AMD's AMD-Vi, ARM's SMMU etc.

Comment: @A.B Yes, but it depends on the OS. I've read in some article that virtualization is not well used by some systems that does not fully make use of the feature . Besides even if someone use an operating system sophisticated for the matter there still a vulnerability to DMA during the pre-boot, which is a critical problem even in updated computers attacked through closed/open chassis attacks on firmware/hardware.

Comment: I could point at this, but I'm sure I'm be told there's something else. Oh I'll still point: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/thunderbolt.html . Now if any arbitrary hardware can be replaced by the attacker, it's game over.

Answer (score 0):

Am not professional in security but i think if the firmware/hardware of all PCI devices is not compromised at least the attacker needs to connect a device with a manipulated firmware/hardware to the host controller in order to perform the DMA attack, the PCI device only does the DMA access but it needs a device connected to it in order to perform the attack ( if it's hardware haven't been manipulated ).

In this quote from qubes.org they talk about the matter.

```
Why is VT-d/AMD-Vi/AMD IOMMU important?

On a system without VT-d/AMD-Vi/AMD IOMMU, there will be no real security benefit to having a separate NetVM, as an attacker could always use a simple DMA attack to go from the NetVM to Dom0. Nonetheless, all of Qubes’ other security mechanisms, such as qube separation, work without VT-d/AMD-Vi/AMD IOMMU. Therefore, a system running Qubes without VT-d/AMD-Vi/AMD IOMMU would still be significantly more secure than one running Windows, Mac, or Linux.
```

Qubes isolate the PCI devices in dom0 vm, so if the PCI device's firmware/hardware have not been manipulated then a DMA attack can't be unless you connect  a device to it ( manipulated wireless adapter/Ethernet card, usb device ... ).
But in my opinion if the hardware/firmware of a PCI device was manipulated an attack ( mostly automated if the RAM/other PCI haven't been modified to integrate a wireless functionality ), on dom0 still will be possible therefore the whole machine would be compromised.